# Compute the differential of a function $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, jacobian

I am struggling a bit in computing the differential of the following function. In particular, I am confused by differentiating w.r.t. $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.

Let $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(\cos(x), \sin(x)) = (\sin(2x)\cos(x), \sin(2x)\sin(x))$.

---

Using the comment of @Fakemistake. I have that the differential is
$$df = \begin{pmatrix} 4sin(x)cos(x) & 2cos^2(x) \\ 2sin^2(x) &4sin(x)cos(x)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: First observation resulted in rewriting $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$. Then let $u=\cos(x)$ and $v=\sin(x)$. Don't forget $u^2+v^2=1$.

Comment: At what level are you asking, e.g., calculus, smooth manifolds, ...?

Comment: Yes, what is your definition for the derivative of $f \colon S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: The domain is (intrinsically) one-dimensional, so your matrix should be $2 \times 1$. Again, it's hard to give a relevant answer without more information about what you mean by "differential". The map $f$ is the restriction to the unit circle of a map $F$ from the plane to itself, whose differential $DF$ is $2 \times 2$ (I haven't checked your matrix), but that's not normally what would be meant by the differential of $f$.